# Adding a jquery script to plugin contact form 7

Tags: plugins, jquery

I have a jquery script that will allow todays date to autopopulate the Date form tag in `contact form 7` plugin.  This is not a function that CF-7 can do without a script.  I don't want my users to have to fill out the date field every time they log in.

I've got as far as knowing I need to install the script into a js directory and to call it in the plugin, but I don't know which directory!

I have a js directory in WP-Admin, one in `WP-content/plugins/includes/contact-form7/js`, and there is a js directory in WP-Includes.

I am using WP version `4.0.44`

Here is the code I want to add, it is called "todays_date":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    $("#dates").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd-M-y'
    }).datepicker('setDate', date);
}.
```

Thank you for any help.  I've looked all over and can't find an answer that will help a complete newbie (to both WP and jquery) like me. I posted on the CF7 forum and got no answer.  I did check this forum first but nothing specified doing this to customize a plugin.

Knowing how to add jquery scripts to plugins to perform functions the plug in cannot do will open up a lot of doors for me.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I use this: https://en-za.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-datepicker/ for my CF7 date-picker.